# How to register a custom Endpoint Mapping in Spring Soap web services

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap

I'm implementing a SOAP client that interacts with some legacy SOAP services.

All of SOAP body requests have the same format, like this:

```
<soap:Body>
   <execute>
      <msg>
      </msg>
   </execute>
</soap:Body>
```

As content, the msg element supports a list of **any** XML tags, so I can send any type of element inside msg: orders, customer, contacts, etc..

All of the requests also have the same action name.

Due to the restrictions/aspects above, if I use spring's [PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/server/endpoint/mapping/PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping.html), since the root element in the soap body is the same for all the requests, each request will fall in the same method of my Endpoint. If I use spring's [SoapActionAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/sites/1.5/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/soap/server/endpoint/mapping/SoapActionAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping.html), since the action is the same for every requests, all of them will fall in the same method again.

The only thing I've got different in the requests, is the requesting URI.
It changes by the name of the operation that I'm invoking. Like:
http://host:port/services/Operation1?Wsdl or
http://host:port/services/Operation2?Wsdl

My idea was to have an endpoint for each type of requests. For example: all request related to products would fit into a "ProductsEndpoint".
I wanted to create a custom endpoint mapping that would extend springs AbstractEndpointMapping. In my implementation I would decide which endpoint to call based on the URI.

But how can I register my custom endpoint mapping in the spring's endpoint mapping chain?

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone has a request like mine explained above, here goes what I've decided to do...

I've create a class MultipleMarshallersPayloadMethodProcessor extending spring `org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.MarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor`. This is the class responsible for marshalling and unmarshalling arguments. In this class I've defined a java.util.map that will associate a given URL to a specific Marshaller. If the current URL request isn't a key in the map, it would use the default Marshaller supplied by the MarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor class.

To register the class as a spring bean:

```
<bean id="marshallingPayloadMethodProcessor"
        class="br.com.tim.fiber.middleware.services.server.helpers.MultipleMarshallersPayloadMethodProcessor">
        <constructor-arg ref="defaultMarshaller" />
        <property name="otherMarshallers">
            <map>
                <entry key="/Operation1?wsdl" value-ref="operation1Marshaller"></entry>
                <entry key="/Operation2?wsdl" value-ref="operation2Marshaller"></entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

And an example of a marshaller:

```
<bean id="operation1Marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="contextPaths">
            <list>
                <value>com.app.dtos.operation1</value>
                <value>com.app.dtos.common</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

With this setup I was able to marshall and unmarshall any request according to the URL. Then I've used the Facade design pattern to create a SOAP Endpoint with a single method that receives all the requests. That method just inspects the URL and delegates to specific endpoints.

```
@Endpoint
public class FacadeEndpoint {
    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://my.namespace.com/services";
    @Autowired
    private RequesEndpointURLExtractor requestUrlExtractor;
    @Autowired
    private OrdersEndpoint ordersEndpoint;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "execute")
    @ResponsePayload
    public ExecuteResponse dispatch(@RequestPayload Execute request) {
        String serviceURL = this.requestUrlExtractor.getCurrentURL();
        ExecuteResponse response = null;

        if (serviceURL.equals(ServiceRequestsEndpoint.CREATE_ENDPOINT_URI)) {
            Operation1DTO serviceRequest = (Operation1DTO) request.getMsg().getAnies().get(0);
}
...
}
```

The RequestEnpointURLExtractor is just a spring bean that extracts the full URL from the request.

```
@Component
public class RequesEndpointURLExtractor {

    public String getCurrentURL() {
        TransportContext ctx = TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext();
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = ((HttpServletConnection) ctx.getConnection()).getHttpServletRequest();

        String pathInfo = httpServletRequest.getPathInfo();
        String queryString = httpServletRequest.getQueryString();

        return pathInfo + "?" + queryString;
    }
}
```

I could create a custom annotation that would have a URL associated, and use that annotation on methods that would process the request with the URL configured. That would be a cleaner solution instead of the if/else if ladder that I have.

But, since this was only for a simple mockup server, the if/else if ladder isn't such a big deal.